# Expand itemgroup of the ListView when one of its items are selected programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

Following are the codes for my wpf listview. there I'm creating listitems programmatically and group them by ItemFamily then when I click the search button item named car is selected. but ItemGroup which contains the item "car" is still collapsed. I want this itemgroup to automatically expanded when its child item is selected programmatically.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<User> items = new List<User>();
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Dhal", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Food" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Dhal", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Food" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Dhal", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Food" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Dhal", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Food" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Car", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Toys" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Bus", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Toys" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Water Gun", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Toys" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Rubics Cube", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Toys" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sun & Fun", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Helth Care" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Face Wash", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Helth Care" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "LED TV 15\"", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Electronics" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sub woofer", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Electronics" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Lava Lamp", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Electronics" });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Play Station Portable", Price = "42", Tax = "A", Barcode = "12345", ItemFamily = "Electronics" });
            lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;

            CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("ItemFamily");
            view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);

            KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(lvUsers, KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle);

            lvUsers.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("ItemFamily", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            lvUsers.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Name", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        }

        public class User
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Price { get; set; }

            public string Tax { get; set; }

            public string ItemFamily { get; set; }

            public string Barcode { get; set; }

            public int index { get; set; }
        }

        private int indexed_items;
        private bool find(string str)
        {
            int i = -1;
            foreach (User item in lvUsers.Items)
            {

                i++;
                if (item.Name.Equals(str))
                {
                    indexed_items = i;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        private void select(string str)
        {
            List<User> items1 = new List<User>();
            foreach (User item in lvUsers.Items)
            {
                if (item.Name.Equals(str))
                {
                    lvUsers.SelectedIndex = indexed_items;
                    lvUsers.ScrollIntoView(item);
                }

                items1.Add(item);
            }

        }

        private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (find("Car"))
            {
                select("Car");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid removed="Aqua">
        <ListView Name="lvUsers" removed="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="45" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn  Width="20" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding space}" />

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Control" Width="410" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="400" Foreground="Black" Height="40" Margin="0" FontSize="20"  />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Control" Width="210" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Price}" Width="200" Foreground="Black" Height="40" Margin="0" FontSize="20"  />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander Name="Expander">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Name="expnder_stackpanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="75">
                                                    <Canvas>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="50" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" Canvas.Left="500" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Top="20" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="400" />
                                                    </Canvas>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Search" Width="200" Height="50"  Name="btnsearch" Click="btnsearch_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I want to do the same. Did you come to any conclusion?